# Consulta em MySQL com AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Criei uma tabela `"usuario"` no `MySQL` contendo nome e senha. Estabeleci uma conexão com o `PHP` e gostaria de fazer uma consulta pelo `AJAX`, para validar esse nome e senha e imprimir uma mensagem dizendo se são válidos ou não. Mas não sei como fazer a parte da consulta nos inputs.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercício Tec Prog I</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#bEntrar").click(function(){
                fLogar();


            });

            function fLogar()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "usuario.php",
                    success:function(dados)
                    {
            }   

        });         
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="usuario.php" method="POST">
    <label>Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" id="tLogin"/>
    <label>Senha</label>
    <input type="text" id="tSenha">
    <button id="bEntrar">Entrar</button>
    <div id="divFilmes"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>


     <?php



 $tLogin = $_POST["tLogin"];
 $tSenha = $_POST["tSenha"];

    //Conectando ao banco de dados
 $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "tecprog");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

    //Consultando banco de dados
 $qryLista = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome = '$tLogin' AND senha = '$tSenha'");    
 while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
    $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
 }    

    //Passando vetor em forma de json
 echo json_encode($vetor);

 ?>
```

Comment: Você quer saber se o usuário existe ou não, é isso?

Comment: Ué, você faz a conexão com OO e dps vai pra procedural, masoq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for só pra verificar se  o usuário existe, basta fazer isso:

```
  $tLogin = $_POST["tLogin"];
  $tSenha = $_POST["tSenha"];

//Conectando ao banco de dados
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "tecprog");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

 if($con->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome ='$tLogin' AND senha = '$tSenha'")->fetch_all()){
    //Usuário existe
    echo 'Existe';
 }else{
    //Usuário não existe
     echo 'Não existe';
 }
```

Seus inputs estavam sem o campo name, tenta assim:

```
<form action="usuario.php" method="POST">
<label>Usuario</label>

<input type="text" id="tLogin" name="tLogin"/>

<label>Senha</label>

<input type="text" id="tSenha" name="tSenha">

<button id="bEntrar">Entrar</button>

<div id="divFilmes"></div>
```

Comment: No success do ajax você decide oque faz com o retorno

Comment: Eu tentei algo do tipo. Mas ele está apresentando o erro "Undefined index" nas seguintes linhas:                                                                         
 $tLogin = $_POST["tLogin"];
  $tSenha = $_POST["tSenha"];

Comment: Ahhhh tá, o post não tá indo, o que o define é o name, vc só colocou o id

Comment: Vou editar aqui

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro olha aí e tenta, oq define o nome do post é o campo name do input, por isso dava dando Undefined, porque você não estava o enviando

Comment: Realmente deu certo haha, Vlw

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro de nada :)